# Can't display custom cell with PFQueryTableViewController (Swift2)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, parseui, pftableviewcell

Using parse.com v1.4 (installed with cocoa pods) with Swift 2 +

I've setup up my PFQueryTableViewController (ParseUI) with a custom cell. I believe everything is hooked up fine, however I can't get the cell to display the value from Parse.com even though I do receive it and can print it (I've debugged it).

I am dequeueing like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrderTableViewCell

    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let pfObject = object {

        // prints expected value, e.g. 1, 2, 3
        print(pfObject["table"])

        // shows "Label" which is my label's default text on the SB!!
        let table = pfObject["table"] as? String
        cell.lblTable.text = table
    }
    return cell
}
```

The rest of my PFQueryTableViewController which seems to load data OK from Parse:
[image]

My custom cell OrderTableViewCell (with some label IBActions):
[image]

SB set-up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the result:

[image]

How can I get the label to display the actual text? What am I missing? I don't want to revert back to standard UITableView due to the additional features I get with Parse UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was as simple as changing

```
let table = pfObject["table"] as? String
```

to

```
let table = String(pfObject["table"])
```